# PowerBI - Rolling Monthly OTD Calculated Column

Tags: powerbi

I am pretty new to PowerBI and I am trying to calculate a rolling "Monthly On-Time Delivery" calculated column.

[image]

[image]

ERROR IMAGE
[image]

ADDED DAILY SHIPMENT COUNT (Disregard the incorrect MTD Shipment Count title)
[image]

Each row represents a single day in the Matrix

For each day I want to get the MonthShippedTotal / (MonthShippedTotal-MonthPastDue), this should give me my rolling on time delivery percentage.

This is what I have so far but the results are way off:

```
> MonthlyOTD =  VAR RowDate = opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE] RETURN
>     CALCULATE (
>         DIVIDE((COUNT(opr_shipments[CREATE_TIMESTAMP])-COUNTAX(opr_shipments,opr_shipments[PAST_DUE]="1")),COUNT(opr_shipments[CREATE_TIMESTAMP]),0),
>         FILTER (
>             opr_shipments,
>             opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE] <= RowDate
>                 && MONTH ( opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE] ) = MONTH ( RowDate ) && YEAR ( opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE] ) = YEAR ( RowDate )
>         )
>     )
```

**MTD Shipments Calc:**

```
MTD Shipments = 
VAR RowDate = opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( opr_shipments[Daily Shipments] ),
        FILTER (
            opr_shipments,
            opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE] <= RowDate
                && MONTH ( opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE] ) = MONTH ( RowDate ) && YEAR ( opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE] ) = YEAR ( RowDate )
        )
    )
```

**Past Due Total Calc:**

```
PastDueTotal = 
VAR RowDate = opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM(opr_shipments[Daily Shipments]),
        FILTER (
            opr_shipments,
            opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE] <= RowDate
                && DAY ( opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE] ) = DAY ( RowDate ) && opr_shipments[PAST_DUE] = "1"
        )
    )
```

For each month this calc would start over.

> My desired output is: Jan 1 | 98% Jan 2 | 98.3% Jan 3 | 95% ... Jan 31
>   | 94.5% Feb 1 | 100%

Comment: What is the structure of your tables? how are being calculated MTD Shipments and Past Due Total measures?

Comment: Alejandro, I updated my question up above.

Comment: Is the Past Due Total MTD too? note you are specifying an additional condition in the filter PAST_DUE = 1

Comment: The Past Due Total is a daily count or total of the number of line items that were past due (i.e. WHERE PAST_DUE=1)

Comment: So for Jan 15 for example I want to count all of the past due items from Jan1-Jan15 and then get the on time %

Comment: Note `Past Due Total` is not cumulative MTD in your example though

Comment: PAST_DUE on each line item is a BOOLEAN, either 1 or 0

Comment: Your absolutely correct, Past Due Total is a Daily aggregation of the records that have PAST_DUE = 1, its not a monthly aggregation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135335/discussion-between-xxphenom22xx-and-alejandro-zuleta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this could work for the `MonthlyOTD` calculated column.

```
MonthlyOTD =
VAR RowDate = opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE]
RETURN
    SUMX (
        FILTER (
            opr_shipments,
            [SHIP_DATE] <= RowDate
                && MONTH ( [SHIP_DATE] ) = MONTH ( RowDate )
                && YEAR ( opr_shipments[SHIP_DATE] ) = YEAR ( RowDate )
        ),
        DIVIDE ( [MTD Shipments], [MTD Shipments] - [PastDueTotal] )
    )
```

I'd create those calculations as measures instead of calculated columns, note measures can be calculated in any context and are affected by filters which usually is desired.

**UPDATE:** It seems OP doesn't require a monthly cumulative total so the final expression was:

```
MonthlyOTD = DIVIDE ( ([MTD Shipment Count] - [Lines]), [MTD Shipment Count] )
```

Comment: Getting some really crazy percentages, see attached image up above.

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx, upload the image to your question not my answer.